# How to select and deselect a row by tapping on it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cell

I have a UITableView with an UITableViewCell, and I want to select them by clicking on it and deselect them by another clicking on them.
First, I have tried it with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // code
}
```

But I have noticed that this function don't get performed when you click a second time on a cell; it gets performed when you click on another cell.
But I want that you can click on several cells which are checked when you click on them.

So I have made this code (simplified):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Selected")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LektionTableViewCell
        if cell.accessoryType == .none {
            print("Type = none")
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            Lektion.insert(Dateien[indexPath.row], at: Lektion.count)
        } else if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            print("Type = check")
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            Lektion.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work correctly:

1. When I click on a cell, the text automatically turn to "Label" (The text it has in the view builder)
2. When I click on a cell with a check, the check doesn't vanish and Xcode says "Type = none"; that is wrong.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: The code cannot work, **never ever** call `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRow`. Add a `Bool` property `selected` to your model, set it in `didSelectRow` and reload the row. In `cellForRow` set the accessoryType depending on `selected`.

Comment: @vadian I have tried it but I don't know how to code this. Can you say it to me in an answer?

Comment: What is the type of `Dateien`? Btw, variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter. And please add `cellForRow` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove following code from your `didSelect` method, as it `dequeReusableCell` should not be used outside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! LektionTableViewCell
        if cell.accessoryType == .none {
            print("Type = none")
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            Lektion.insert(Dateien[indexPath.row], at: Lektion.count)
        } else if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            print("Type = check")
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            Lektion.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        }
```

You can get cell instance using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` inside `idSelectRow`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath) as? LektionTableViewCell {
        // Perform your operations here.....
    }

}
```

Now, solution to your query, that for didSelect is not called upon click (unless you select another row). **Allow multiple selection to your table view**.

**Note:** Use a flag (boolean) variable in your table array to set selection status while your table is loading data.

Comment: But why the if before `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath) as? LektionTableViewCell {`?

Comment: It not compulsory to use "if" before "let cell = .... "    You can directly use >> "let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath) as! LektionTableViewCell"      It's precaution to prevent exception... I generally used to work with multiple tables & cell integrated with each other...

Comment: I have had the same idea, only 'let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath)'

Comment: And then the other code. What does the end changes?

Comment: Share you code for function tableview - cellForRowAtIndexPath,  in your question, so you can get a better help.

Comment: And I have found an other error at '            Lektion.remove(at: indexPath.row)'. If you make a check on the first, third and fifth cell, and then you click again on the fifth, it wants to delete the fifth string of Dateien, but there are only 3. How can I make that it deletes the cell I have tapped on?

Comment: I think you may go through this once... https://www.appcoda.com/model-view-controller-delete-table-row-from-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I add it here. 
From your code we don't see where you store the data for populating your cells. So I don't know if this can help you but suppose you have an array with your objects, one approach would be to set a "isSelected" variable on your object on the `didSelectRowAt indexPath` method and then call `tableview.reloadData()`. Something like this:

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            myObjects[indexPath.row].isSelected = !myObjects[indexPath.row].isSelected 
            tableView.reloadData() 
      }
```

Then on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, when you create your cells you could easily set the accessoryType to either .checkmark or .none depending on the flag of your object. 
Like this:

```
cell.accessoryType = myObjects[indexPath.row].isSelected ? .checkMark : .none
```

Hope that helps.